# Get visible controls by position

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument, flowdocumentscrollviewer

I have a `FlowDocument` with much content inside. I need to get the controls that are currently in the visible area.

With the following code I was able to get the current scrolling Position.

```
DependencyObject obj = FlowDocumentScrollViewerCtrl;

do
{
    if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj) > 0)
    {
        obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj as Visual, 0);
    }
}
while (!(obj is ScrollViewer));

ScrollViewer sv = obj as ScrollViewer;
```

How can I get the controls within the visible area?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to recursively descend the Visual tree using `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount` and `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild()` and check each Visual using this procedure:

1. Throw out any visual that isn't interesting to your code (eg you may only care about Controls)
2. Get each Visual's bounding box using `new Rect(0, 0, visual.ActualWidth, visual.ActualHeight)`.  This will give you the bounding box in the Visual's coordinate system.
3. Use the transform returned by `visual.TransformToAncestor(viewer)` to transform the bounding box into the viewer's coordinate system.
4. Check to see if the transformed visual's bounding box intersects the viewer's bounding box.  A rough check can be done by taking the minimum and maximum X and Y of the visual bounding box corners and just comparing one axis at a time.  This is easier than full rectangle intersection, and should serve for most purposes.

This will tell you all the visuals in the visible area.  If you want to map to `FrameworkContentElement`s such as `<Paragraph>`, just check out the Content property of the `ContentPresenter`s you run across in your tree walk.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ray for your answer. I followed your tips in some points yesterday and thats the working code for my problem:

```
public class FrameworkElementInfo
{
    Point _position             = new Point();
    FrameworkElement _element   = null;

    public Point Position
    {
        get { return _position; }
        set { _position = value; }
    }

    public FrameworkElement FrameworkElement
    {
        get { return _element; }
        set { _element = value; }
    }
}

public class ScrollViewPositionManager
{
    ScrollViewer _scrollViewer              = null;
    List<FrameworkElementInfo> _elements    = new List<FrameworkElementInfo>();
    double _zoom                            = 100.0;

    public ScrollViewPositionManager(ScrollViewer scrollViewer, double zoom)
    {
        _scrollViewer = scrollViewer;
        _zoom = zoom;
    }

    public void RegisterElement(FrameworkElement element, Boolean registerOnly)
    {
        FrameworkElementInfo info = new FrameworkElementInfo();

        if (!registerOnly)  info.Position = CalculatePosition(element);
        info.FrameworkElement   = element;

        _elements.Add(info);
    }

    public void RecalculatePositions()
    {
        int Counter = 0;

        foreach(FrameworkElementInfo info in _elements)
        {
            Counter += 1;
            info.Position = CalculatePosition(info.FrameworkElement);
        }
    }

    public List<FrameworkElement> GetElementsInViewPort()
    {
        List<FrameworkElement> elements = new List<FrameworkElement>();

        double verticalOffsetHigh = _scrollViewer.ViewportHeight + _scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;

        foreach (FrameworkElementInfo info in _elements)
        {
            Point point = info.Position;

            if (point.Y >= _scrollViewer.VerticalOffset &&
                point.Y <= verticalOffsetHigh)
            {
                elements.Add(info.FrameworkElement);
            }
        }

        return elements;
    }

    private Point CalculatePosition(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        GeneralTransform elementTransform = element.TransformToAncestor(_scrollViewer);
        Point elementPoint = elementTransform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        Point transformedPoint = new Point(elementPoint.X, elementPoint.Y);

        transformedPoint = GetZoomedPoint(elementPoint, _zoom, _scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset, _scrollViewer.VerticalOffset);

        return transformedPoint;
    }

    static public Point GetZoomedPoint(Point unzoomedPoint, double zoom, double offsetX, double offsetY)
    {
        Point zoomedPoint = new Point();

        double zoomFactor = 100.0 / zoom;

        zoomedPoint.X = offsetX + unzoomedPoint.X * zoomFactor;
        zoomedPoint.Y = offsetY + unzoomedPoint.Y * zoomFactor;

        return zoomedPoint;
    }

    public int ElementCount
    {
        get { return _elements.Count; }
    }

    public FrameworkElement GetFirstElement()
    {
        FrameworkElement firstElement = null;

        if(_elements.Count > 0) firstElement = _elements[0].FrameworkElement;

        return firstElement;
    }

    public FrameworkElement GetLastElement()
    {
        FrameworkElement lastElement = null;

        if (_elements.Count > 0) lastElement = _elements[_elements.Count-1].FrameworkElement;

        return lastElement;
    }

    public FrameworkElement GetNextElement(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        FrameworkElement nextElement = null;
        int index = GetElementIndex(element);

        if(index != -1 && index != _elements.Count -1)
        {           
            nextElement = _elements[index + 1].FrameworkElement;
        }

        return nextElement;
    }

    public FrameworkElement GetPreviousElement(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        FrameworkElement previousElement = null;
        int index = GetElementIndex(element);

        if (index > 1)
        {
            previousElement = _elements[index - 1].FrameworkElement;
        }

        return previousElement;
    }

    public int GetElementIndex(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        return _elements.FindIndex(
                            delegate(FrameworkElementInfo currentElement)
                            {
                                if(currentElement.FrameworkElement == element) return true;
                                return false;
                            }
        );
    }
}
```

I use a register function for the elements of interest and working only on them. The zoom is only neccessary for a FlowDocument I think. This code should work on every control which uses a ScrollViewer.
I would appreciate if anyone may comment this if this is a practical solution.